# Android ImageView - need sharp images

Tags: android, image, imageview

Im kinda new here and also not so skilled programmer of android apps.
I searched the internet and read a lot of tips and "tutorials" but i cant figure this out by myself.

I got an android app ( which i programming ) and i cant get scaled images right and they dont look

```
ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/cat2text17"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:minHeight="299dp"
            android:maxHeight="299dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:minWidth="192dp"
            android:maxWidth="192dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:contentDescription="jobs_image"
```

So the main problem is that image is not sharp.
I got my images in drawable folder ( not drawable-hdpi or ldpi and such )

This is result. My phone is Lenovo P780 but i think it doesnt matter.
[Result is here](http://caffeineworks.cz/screen3.jpeg)

Maybe just a little edit. Entire code of layout is here

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#ffd52c4d"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:onClick="buttonBack"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/back_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Jobs and My Town"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/second_relativelayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/NoText"
        android:background="@drawable/with_btn"
        android:onClick="buttonNoText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxHeight="38dp"
        android:maxWidth="320dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/second_relativelayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_part3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
        android:onClick="Play"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/dalsi_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageer"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="Another" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/predchozi_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageer"
        android:onClick="Previous"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout_part3"
    android:minWidth="192dp"
    android:minHeight="299dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/cat2text17"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:minHeight="299dp"
        android:maxHeight="299dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:minWidth="192dp"
        android:maxWidth="192dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:contentDescription="jobs_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kina answered your own question:

> I got my images in drawable folder ( not drawable-hdpi or ldpi and
>   such )

Images in the drawable folder *will* be scaled depending on a device's DPI, so it will be scaled to 2x its orginal size on a XHDPI device (eg a 4.7" device with 1280x720 screen). To avoid this you should always provide properly scaled image to each dpi-specific drawable folder.

I would recommend you to read Android's guide on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) again.